# How to show ListBox Items when TreeView Item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, treeview

So I have a task of building a mail application for school. I am having a problem with one of the parts.

I have a `TreeView` and a `ListBox`. `TreeView` has few items in it (Inbox, trash, draft). Now what I am trying to do, is that when I select and `TreeView` item certain `ListBox` Items will appear in the `ListBox`. (purpose of the `ListBox` is to show the mails in that "folder").

I have been looking into this, and there are some suggestions with `ListAray` and `DataBinding`, but I am very new and have no idea how to implement any of those.

What I have at this poit is:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10"  Name="treeView1" Width="100" FontSize="14" SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Prejeto" IsSelected="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Prebrano" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Neprebrano" />
    </TreeViewItem>

    <TreeViewItem Header="Poslano" />
    <TreeViewItem Header="Osnutki" />
    <TreeViewItem Header="Izbrisano" />
    <TreeViewItem Header="Nezaželeno" />
    <TreeViewItem />
</TreeView>
```

XAML `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox Name="seznamSporocil" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" MouseDoubleClick="seznamSporocil_MouseDoubleClick" />
```

`SelectedItemChanged`:

```
private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{

}
```

Comment: well if your not comfortable with `DataBinding` or Array Collections, it's probably a good idea to take a break and look into them topics firstly than just take scraps of code and blindly following advice. http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Hei, thank you for the suggestion. I have been reading these, but when it comes to the implementation I am unable to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

When working with WPF, [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) is your best friend. Just bind `ItemsSource` of list box with some collection property of tree view's selected item.

**Update**.

Here's the complete sample (just create WPF Application project).
Model:

```
public class MailFolder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MailItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items ?? (items = new ObservableCollection<MailItem>());
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MailItem> items;

    public ObservableCollection<MailFolder> SubFolders
    {
        get
        {
            return subFolders ?? (subFolders = new ObservableCollection<MailFolder>());
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MailFolder> subFolders;
}

public class MailItem
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TreeView x:Name="MailTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MailFolder}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubFolders}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>

        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Items, ElementName=MailTreeView}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MailItem}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is data context setup:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new[] 
        {
            new MailFolder
            {
                Name = "Prejeto",
                SubFolders = 
                {
                    new MailFolder
                    {
                        Name = "Prebrano",
                        Items = 
                        {
                            new MailItem { Subject = "A" },
                            new MailItem { Subject = "B" },
                            new MailItem { Subject = "C" },
                        }
                    },
                    new MailFolder
                    {
                        Name = "Neprebrano",
                        Items = 
                        {
                            new MailItem { Subject = "D" },
                            new MailItem { Subject = "E" },
                        }
                    },
                },
                Items = 
                {
                    new MailItem { Subject = "M" },
                    new MailItem { Subject = "N" },
                }
            },
            new MailFolder
            {
                Name = "Poslano",
                Items = 
                {
                    new MailItem { Subject = "F" },
                    new MailItem { Subject = "G" },
                }
            },
            new MailFolder
            {
                Name = "Osnutki",
                Items = 
                {
                    new MailItem { Subject = "H" },
                }
            },
            new MailFolder
            {
                Name = "Izbrisano",
                Items = 
                {
                    new MailItem { Subject = "I" },
                    new MailItem { Subject = "J" },
                    new MailItem { Subject = "K" },
                }
            },
            new MailFolder
            {
                Name = "Nezaželeno",
                Items = 
                {
                    new MailItem { Subject = "L" },
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Note, that if you want to reflect changes, made to properties of your model classes, you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

Comment: OK, this seems to be the way to go. But can you also help me how to create a collection of items for each treviewitem?
For example. I have tree items in treeview and for each i would like to display five items in the listbox. How do I add them to each treeviewitem?